# Angularjs - common module for 2 different angular website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

i have two different angular app( this two apps are running different work space and different angular folder structure) in this 2 app
     i having a common  module "report". Now I am written this module separately (same file each app). Here my question is I can make this module
     common module for two apps (if we change the code in one file the functionality reflects in 2 app side) and this two app we having different
     user login and different tokens. Is it possible to handle 2 different workspace app login and calling this module on common app.

Answer (score 0):

So, i think this is what you're looking for.. in Angular 1, there are a couple ways to build an app.

Method 1:

```
angular.module('module.name', []);

angular.module('module.name').controller(...);
angular.module('module.name').directive(...);
```

So, this way, you could build all the application parts that you need, like controllers and directives.

The other way to do it is to create separate instances of modules, with their own controllers and directives and then explicitly reference them..

Method 2:

```
angular.module('module.one', []).controller(...);

angular.module('module.two', ['module.one']).controller(...);
angular.module('module.three', ['module.one']).controller(...);
```

So, if you were to create a module that would be shared between the two apps you have you can create it in a separate folder, and then explicitly include it into each separate app that you're working on (see method 2 above).

When I have created a public and admin version of an app (two apps) which both share modules i've done this. I also don't really separate the folder structure under the thinking that i could reuse a lot of the directives and providers/services.

I hope this answers your question.